# What is the name of this graph transformation from Akiyama's proof from 1983?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a graph and $H$ be a (not neccessarily induced) subgraph of $G$ with vertices $a,b,c,d$ and edge $ab$. $G$ is now transformed by replacing edge $ab$ in $H$ with edges $ac$ and $bd$. So our subgraph is changed from $K_2+2K_1$ to $2K_2$. This transformation is crucial in Akiyama's proof from 1983 that for every given graph $G$, a $\Delta G$-regular graph $H$ containing $G$ exists (see [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Regular%20graphs%20containing%20a%20given%20graph&publication_year=1983&author=J.%20Akiyama&author=H.%20Era&author=F.%20Harary#)).

**Does this transformation have a specific name in the literature?** Because I need to provide an name and would rather use a familiar one than making up my own.

Comment: If I were to provide my own, I would either choose "Akiyama switch" or "open gate transformation"